# Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: html, jsp

I want to retrieve data from database, where username = entered by the user during login.
Username is entered by user in html 
But I am getting error as: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
 Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
 Stream closed.

my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

String uname= request.getParameter("UserName");
try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas","root","rass");  
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Student_Data where UserName="+uname);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

%>


<table rules="all" border="">
<%

while (rs.next()) {
%>
<tr>
<td>FirstName: </td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td></tr>
<td>LastName: </td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(2));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>UserName: </td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(3));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(4));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>DateOfBirth: </td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(5));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>E-Mail</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(6));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile.No</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(7));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(8));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(9));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>City</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(10));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>PinCode</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(11));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>State</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(12));%></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(13));%></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Hobbies</td>
<td><%out.println(rs.getString(14));%> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Qualification</td><td>Sl.No</td><td>Examination</td><td>Board</td><td>Percentage</td><td>Year of Passing</td>
</tr>       
<tr>
<td></td><td>1</td><td>Class X</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(15));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(16));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(17));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td>2</td><td>Class XII</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(18));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(19));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(20));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td>3</td><td>Graduation</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(21));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(22));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(23));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Course Applied</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(24));%>
</td>
</tr>

</table>


<%
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
out.close();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not invoke `out.close` in your jsp page,jsp will do it for you

So just remove below code:

```
<%
}
}
//remove below code
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
out.close();
%>
```

For your query sql,since you have use `PreparedStatement` ,so you need pass parameter like `ps.setString()` instead of write in the sql directly,so change to below:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas","root","rass");  
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Student_Data where UserName=?");
ps.setString(1,uname);
```

Comment: yes i removed out.close(),  but not getting any output, if i hardcode username im getting output but if im trying to use like this: "PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Student_Data where UserName="+uname);"    not getting any output

Comment: FYI, I was writing a comment when you removed your answer in the dup ;) "That's me, even if this is an improvement, the query generated is correct. This is not the problem. (It is a possible injection, but it should work). And you should simply flag for a duplicate instead of copy pasting your answer ;)"

Comment: @AxelH use `PreparedStatement` can avoid sql injection and I do not have the privilege to mark it as duplicate