# Retrieve data html page to jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to get UserName from html to jsp page so that based on UserName it Shows the particular user data through jsp page, i tried many but did not get the required output. If i hardcode the UserName in jsp page then im getting the data from database.
please ignore the commented part.
my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Login Page</title>
    <h1  align="center">Student Login Page</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Servlet_LoginPage" action="Servlet_LoginPage" method="post">

<table align="center">
<!-- 
<tr>
<td>
<select name="UserSelect" >
    <option label="Select User"> </option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  </select>

</td>
</tr>
 -->
<tr>
<td>UserName </td><td><input type="text" name=UserName></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name=pwd></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit">
<input type="reset" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

my Jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Details</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
response.setContentType("text/html");
String uname=request.getParameter("UserName");
try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas","root","rass");  
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Student_Data where UserName="+uname);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

%>


<table>
<%

while (rs.next()) {
%>
<tr>
<td height="25" >FirstName: </td><td colspan="2"><%out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td>
<td height="25" >LastName: </td><td colspan="3"><%out.println(rs.getString(2));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >UserName: </td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(3));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >Password: </td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(4));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >DateOfBirth: </td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(5));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >E-Mail</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(6));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >Mobile.No</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(7));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >Gender</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(8));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >Address</td colspan="5"><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(9));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >City</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(10));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >PinCode</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(11));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >State</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(12));%></td></tr>
<tr><td height="25" >Country</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(13));%></td></tr>
<tr>
<td height="25" >Hobbies</td>
<td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(14));%> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4">Qualification</td><td height="25" >Sl.No</td><td>Examination</td><td>Board</td><td>Percentage</td><td>Year of Passing</td>
</tr>       
<tr>
<td height="25" >1</td><td>Class X</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(15));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(16));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(17));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="25" >2</td><td>Class XII</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(18));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(19));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(20));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="25" >3</td><td>Graduation</td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(21));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(22));%></td><td><%out.println(rs.getString(23));%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="25" >Course Applied</td><td colspan="5"><%out.println(rs.getString(24));%>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

<%
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you should start creating correct HTML `name=UserName` should be `name="UserName"`. This might be that simple. FYI: you should quickly look into Servlet and JSTL instead of adding the logic in your view.

Comment: It would also be a lot better to post to a servlet rather than having java in your JSP.  JSP should be the `V` part of MVC

Comment: Last thing, please check how to use `PreparedStatement` because my name is `'' OR 1=1`. SQLInjection from an HTML form is the worst think you can propose..

Comment: Hey Indian guys,you have post a duplicate answer,I just updated my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836702/exception-occurred-when-flushing-data-with-root-cause-java-io-ioexception-stre

Answer (score 0):

You have not write the HTML correctly.

```
<td>UserName </td><td><input type="text" name=UserName></td>
```

You need quotes for the name value

```
<td>UserName </td><td><input type="text" name="UserName"></td>
```

I have run a test with

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="#">
        <input name=test/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The query receive with a "foobar" value :

> file:///C:/tmp/test.html?test%2F=foobar#

Why, because here is how the HTML is interpreted on a older version of Firefox (can't check with more recent for the moment) :

```
<input name="test/">
```

So the parameter name is not the one you expect. Use correct syntax in the HTML, it should fix the problem.

---

Then I need to tell you this is an incorrect usage of `PreparedStatement`, you need to use parameters :

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Student_Data where UserName=?");
ps.setString(uname);
```

---

That way, the request will have a parameter `UserName`
FYI: using a `<table>` for the design is depreciated by web developer for at least a decade ;)

Comment: will the browser add `"` itself when missing?

Comment: Not correctly, based on the browser I would guess. I have added an example @lucumt